# Loading static resources from a Grails custom tag, with disposition: 'head'

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, custom-tags

I'm trying to write a Grails custom tag that (among other things) triggers inclusion of a resource, so something like `<myTags:view name="foo"/>` would load, say, `js/views/foo.js`. And I want it loaded with `disposition: 'head'`.

I could use `<r:external/>`, but that wouldn't put it in the `<head>`, it would just produce an inline `<script/>` tag. And I could use `<r.script/>`, but that doesn't let me reference a path; I'd have to have my custom tag read the file and dump it to `out`.

Now, if `foo.js` was its own module, I could do something like: `r.require([module: 'foo'])`, but it's not; part of the point of this is that I don't want to have to declare all of these files in `ApplicationResources.groovy`. But maybe I could have `ApplicationResources.groovy` create the modules programmatically, by reading through the available files -- is that possible? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Really the point is to create modules and just include them in the pages that need them. I see what you are trying to do, however I don't think it will work in practice. Potentially you could load that file more than once if you use the tag more than once. You will be better off if you follow the Grails conventions.

Comment: I know from experience that if I ask developers to remember every time they create a view to create a module entry in ApplicationResources.groovy, and every time they use a view to ensure there's an <r:require/> tag, they're going to forget and we're going to hit the same issues over and over. I'd rather not violate DRY.

Comment: Hmm, it looks like actually <r:external/> *is* supposed to put it in the head, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up going in the direction of having `ApplicationResources.groovy` create modules programmatically, so the custom tag can use `<r:require/>`.

The idea is, for each Backbone view, under `web-app/myApp/views`, there's a Backbone view in a `.js` file, and a Handlebars template in a `.handlebars` file (with the same name, by convention). The `.handlebars` file gets declared as an ordinary module, but gets precompiled by the Handlebars-Resources plugin.

Some code in `ApplicationResources.groovy` finds all the views and creates corresponding resource modules:

```
GrailsApplication grailsApplication = Holders.getGrailsApplication()
File viewsDir = grailsApplication.parentContext.getResource("myApp/views").file;
if (viewsDir.exists() && viewsDir.isDirectory() && viewsDir.canRead()) {
    String[] viewsJS = viewsDir.list().findAll { name -> 
        name.endsWith("View.js") 
    }
    String[] views = viewsJS.collect { name ->
        name.substring(0, name.length() - ".js".length())
    }

    for (view in views) {
        "${view}" {
            dependsOn 'backbone', 'backbone_relational', 'handlebars'
            resource url: "dpg/views/${view}.handlebars", 
                     attrs: [type: 'js'], 
                     disposition: 'head'
            resource url: "dpg/views/${view}.js", 
                     disposition: 'head'

        }
    }
}
```

Then the taglib:

```
class ViewsTagLib {
    static namespace = "myApp"

    def view = { attrs ->
        r.require(module: "${attrs.name}View")
        out << "<${attrs.tagName} id='${attrs.id}'></${attrs.tagName}>"
    }
}
```

Invoking it in a GSP:

```
<myApp:view tagName="div" name="foo" id="foo1"/>
<myApp:view tagName="div" name="foo" id="foo2"/>
```

Produces:

```
<html>
    <head>
        ...
        <!--
            Automagically generated modules (included only once).
            Should put these in the same bundle, but handlebars-resources
            gets confused.
        -->
        <script src="/myApp/static/bundle-bundle_fooView_handlebars.js" 
                type="text/javascript" ></script>
        <script src="/myApp/static/bundle-bundle_fooView_head.js" 
                type="text/javascript" ></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
        <div id="foo1"></div> <!-- backbone placeholder for 1st view instance-->
        <div id="foo2"></div> <!-- backbone placeholder for 2nd view instance-->
    </body>
</html>
```

It's not pretty but the mess is mostly hidden, and it should cut down considerably on boilerplate and on opportunities to forget to add magic strings to multiple files.